# Using a box of old X-10 stuff

Tags: x-10

I have just been given a bunch of old X-10 stuff including 
CM11A Computer Interface
D-shell-9-pin-Serial-connector to RJ11 (I think)
RR501 Transceiver Module
LM465 Lamp Module and several SR227 Split Receptacle Module.

I am not a newbie to computers, programming and Arduinos so would like to see if I can incorporate these into my home automation network running Arduino+nRF24LO1 and controlled by my own windows-PC software.

Can someone please point me at where to get started with the CM11A and getting it to talk to a USB serial converter? OR - can I directly access the RR501 via some form of radio? Reading the manual it says RR501 can transmit control to and from all other X-10 devices on the 110v wiring. Sounds good to me.

Any other information will be a great help and a great start to save me reinventing he wheel with this old stuff. I am optimistic enough to think it must have already been done a bunch of times.

I have already found some stuff, but so far nothing useful with the older X-10 components.

Comment: Have you tried googling ***Arduino X10*** or ***X10 serial protocol***? One of the first links is the Arduino to X10 rj11 library.

Comment: @Passerby Thanks, but I had already found that stuff and the RJ11 article is using a later model controller than the CM11A. But as Mark points out below, this exercise may all just be for entertainment. :)

Answer (score 1):

I started using the CM11 and the RR501, among other X10 components back in the 90's, and I still use them. (I first used X10 in the late 70's). One warning I need to make: X10 has become less and less reliable with the advent of switching power-supplies. When X10 first came out, home power was pretty quiet, but today there is a lot of noise from switching on the AC line that often swamps the X10 signal. I've bought a number of LED light bulbs recently that have completely disabled my X10 network when I turned them on. Part of the problem with the X10 protocol is that the commands are sent out blind - no acknowledgements. So if a command gets lost, it's lost for good, and things simply don't work. This applies to both the power-line X10 and RF X10 protocols. Now on to the meat.

The CM11A:

I have the programming manual for the CM11A, try googling "CM11A Serial Interface Protocol.txt". The protocol is overly complicated for what it needs to do, and I have not found a USB to serial convertor that it works with (but it's been a few years since I looked). I use it from a standard RS232 port on an old PC. I also have the schematic and someone's rewrite of its firmware (PIC16C58), but I doubt that either of those would be useful to you.

The CM11A has a built-in clock and an internal EEProm. Commands can be pre-loaded to be run a specific times, so it works well as a standalone controller. I don't use it that way.

The RR501:

The RR501 is both an appliance controller (no dimming) and a RF to power-line bridge. The RF portion of X10 uses an ASK modulated 310MHZ signal that the RR510 can receive. It then repeats the received command in the power-line protocol, to either control a device directly or to inform the CM11A. But although the CM11A can handle all housecodes, the RR501 only handles the one that you set. If you have any of the RF X10 motion sensors or keychain remotes, the RR501 is a necessary ingredient to get those RF commands onto the power-line.

If you have any problems finding the documentation, let me know, and we can figure out how to get what I have to you.

Comment: Thanks for that. I too had X-10 stuff back in probably the early to mid 90s. Cannot remember much other than I tore it all out and offered it up at a swap meet. I remember it being very unreliable even then. We have powerline networking for some of outlying sheds (Farmer) so I guess that will make this attempt even less reliable, but it was free so will give it a try anyway. The powerline networking affected some of our digital heating thermostats so they had to go as the network is not optional. I have just ordered a DB9-USB converted claimed to work (another forum) so will see :)

Comment: Mark, I do have two remotes with it, one I guess barely small enough to be called a keychain remote. :) I have just found the protocol.txt and will now wait for the DB9-USB to arrive.

Comment: The USB/DB9 from Amazon (ASIN B00J4N9T9C) works as does the old software albeit in an x86 tablet with an OTG cable. The X10 Lamp Control also seems to work OK with the Powerline Network, well so far. I am looking for some Pascal/Delphi components or even some C++ to convert to save reinventing the wheel. So far no luck, found a few Python APIs but not really any help. Thoughts? Suggestions? Anyone?